# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

everyone. I have this issue. So gradle sync is getting failed. I have tried many methods but all in vain. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

[Gradle Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmpNG.png)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfCa8.png)

Comment: Go to settings and find build and execution after that click on gradle and uncheck offline work and click on Ok. Now sync......

Comment: @RohitSuthar It was already unchecked. But for a try i did it check and save. then i sync it. then another error. Again i uncheck it. but same problem.

Comment: ok for admob ads add this dependency--- 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1' instead of what you are doing

Comment: ok @RohitSuthar but i didn't use firebase. So should i use this?

Comment: yes you can use this

Comment: no problem.......

Comment: @RohitSuthar I have also use -- implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1' . Beside this or should i remove this one?

Comment: remove implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1' and add this implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1;

Comment: @RohitSuthar, i tried it but doesn't work for me. But after research i tried --- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30' this dependency. And it worked for me. Thanks fro your time and help.